# freezing form after clicking button

Tags: c#

I have a problem regarding to payment button.
I don't encounter an error before building, but after building and clicking the payment button it hangs. I think its because of lblTotalPrice.text, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int totalCost;
    public double holDer;



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.cbo1.Items.AddRange(new object[] { "Lechon Kawali - 200", "Bicol Express - 300"
            ,"Adobo - 350" });

    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lb1.Items.Add(cbo1.SelectedItem);

        lb1.SelectedIndex = lb1.SelectedIndex ;

        int z = 0;

        if (cbo1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            z = z + 1;
        }

        if (cbo1.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            z = z + 2;
        }
        if (cbo1.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            z = z + 3;
        }

        switch(z)
        {
            case 1:
                totalCost = totalCost + 200;
                break;
            case 2:
                totalCost = totalCost + 300;
                break;
            case 3:
                totalCost = totalCost + 350;
                break;
        }

        lblSubTotalCost.Text = ("Php " + totalCost.ToString());


    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int deleteCost = 0;
        int itemCost = 0;
        foreach (int selectedIndex in lb1.SelectedIndices)
        {
            itemCost = int.Parse(lb1.Items[selectedIndex].ToString().Split('-')[1]);
            deleteCost += itemCost; lb1.Items.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);
        }

        totalCost = totalCost - deleteCost;

        lblSubTotalCost.Text = ("Php " + totalCost.ToString());

        lb1.Items.Remove(lb1.SelectedItem);
        if (lb1.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            lb1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("No orders");


    }

    private void lblVAT_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Add();
    }
    private void lblSubTotalCost_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        multiply();
        Add();
    }
    public void multiply()
    {
        int a;
        double b = 0.12;
        bool Valid = int.TryParse(totalCost.ToString(), out a);

        if (Valid)
            lblVAT.Text =  (a * b).ToString();
        else
            lblVAT.Text = "No VAT entered";

    }

    private void lbTotalPrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Add();
    }


    public void Add()
    {
        int a;
        int b;

        bool AValid = int.TryParse(totalCost.ToString(), out a);
        bool BValid = int.TryParse(lblVAT.Text, out b);

        if (AValid && BValid)
        {
           lblTotalPrice.Text = ("Php " + (a + b).ToString());

        }


    }

    private void btnPayment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        holDer = double.Parse(tbPayment.Text) - double.Parse(lblTotalPrice.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Change: " + holDer.ToString());

    }

}
```

Comment: do you get any error message? or it just hangs?

Comment: Did you try to debug the code and figure out until which line the code executes good and after which line it hangs the form. You can assign values of payment and price texboxes to some variables and see if they are good for parsing to double while debugging.

Comment: @NicoRiff after building and clicking the payment button the error message says (Input string was not in a correct format.)

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i debug the code and it runs but after typing and at the payment box and click payment button. it hangs and show the error (Input string was not in a correct format.).

Comment: That means that the one of the textbox value is not in correct format to be converted to double. Check the value of textboxes in debug mode to see whats wrong with them.

Comment: What to you type in the payment box?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya for example the totalcost of order is 250. the customer will pay 500. i will put 500 in payment box.

Comment: Can you debug the code and see if the values are correct when you click the button. You can also check for cause what is being suspected by Moo-Juice . Label changed event and Add method are calling each other so they might go in jnfite

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

As you stated in your comments, your problem it is not that your application hangs, but the problem is that you are getting a `Input string was not in a correct format` Exception.

That it seems is from this block:

```
private void btnPayment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    holDer = double.Parse(tbPayment.Text) - double.Parse(lblTotalPrice.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Change: " + holDer.ToString());
}
```

As it is a not very complex code, your problem seems to be when you are casting your textboxes to Double. Be sure that you are using the correct separator for double values and that you not have any strange characters in `tbPayment`

Try using TryParse method:

```
double res;

if(double.TryParse(tbPayment.Text, out res))
{
    holDer = res - double.Parse(lblTotalPrice.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Change: " + holDer.ToString());
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Input a correct format");
}
```

Comment: what is the value of tbPayment.Text?

Comment: and what is the value of lblTotalPrice.Text?

Comment: i will input 300 in the tbpayment and the lblTotalPrice is 200 im expecting change: 100 when i click the button. but (FormatException was unhanded.) shows.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's because the `lblTotalPrice_TextChanged` event-handler calls `Add()` which then changes the `lblTotalPrice.Text` property, causing the event to fire again, ad -infinitum?

Comment: Quite possible.

Comment: @Mark have you debugged the click event and see what happens?

Comment: yes. after debugging and click the payment button the error shows(FormatException was unhanded.)

Comment: i change the lblTotalCost.Text to lblVAT both have Add(); the button work. what codes do i have to change for lblTotalCost?